# Rails: serializing a model's validators into json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been working with Rails and a number of frontend js frameworks and libs, including Ember, Angular, and React. While all three libraries are powerful in their own regard, one pain point (for me at least) has always been form validation. I've always hated having to keep my model validations (in Rails) in sync with my form validations (in Ember/Angular/React).

Lately, I've been attempting to serialize a model's validators into json. However, while calling `as_json` on a record will give me back a `json` hash, it doesn't give me the type of validators for a particular attribute.

For example, let's say I have a model called `Assignment`. When I create a new `Assignment` record and call `_validators` on it, this is what I get.

```
pry(main)> Assignment.new._validators
=> 
{
  :title=>[#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x0000010e123900 @attributes=  [:title], @options={}>],
  :full_prompt=>[#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x0000010e122e60 @attributes=[:full_prompt], @options={}>],
  :submission_window=>[#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x0000010e1223c0 @attributes=[:submission_window], @options={}>]
}
```

Now here's what I get when I add on the `as_json` call:

```
pry(main)> Assignment.new._validators.as_json
=> 
{
  "title"=>[{"attributes"=>["title"], "options"=>{}}],
  "full_prompt"=>[{"attributes"=>["full_prompt"], "options"=>{}}],
  "submission_window"=>[{"attributes"=>["submission_window"], "options"=>{}}]
}
```

As you can see, calling `as_json` removes what types of `validators` were attached to a model's attribute.

Has anybody run into a similar situation and/or has a workaround? Thanks for any help!

Kurt

Answer (score 1):

this should work better... the attributes and options hash will be a sub-hash which will be the value of a hash where the key is the validator class.. all of course themselves sub-hashes under the attributes

```
hash = {}
Assignment._validators.each { |k, v| v.each {|val| hash[k] ||= {}; hash[k][val.class.to_s] = val }}
hash.as_json
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails adds a method to `Object` called `as_json`. As you can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c0965004486f2ea5a9656ba718a3377c9614f97d/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb#L45) it checks to see if the object in question responds to `to_hash` (which `ActiveModel::Validator` does not by default).

The fallback it to invoke `instance_values.as_json(options)` which is how you're getting the default JSON.

I would implement the `to_hash` method on `ActiveModel::Validator` and you can put whatever information in there you'd like.

**initializers/active_model_validator.rb**

```
class ActiveModel::Validator
  def to_hash
    {} # custom implementation here...
  end
end
```

If you want to maintain the default JSON and simply append additional information to it you could do something like

**initializers/active_model_validator.rb**

```
class ActiveModel::Validator
  def to_hash
    instance_values.tap do |hash|
      # custom implementation here...
    end        
  end
end
```