# Is there any way to serialize model validators to json OR any other common pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, models

I have SPA and few models, I want to create form for REST api, but I don't want to duplicate validators data in JS and Ruby.

All I want is to get validators data(required, read-only, type, default, choices, name, label, help_text) from rails and render form from it.

**The problem is** I don't see any solution to serialize model into json. With Python, Django REST Framework, I can make OPTIONS request and it will give me full information about model fields, parsers, methods, etc. Is there any similar solution for Rails?

Answer (score 1):

There is validation reflection available in Rails 3 and Rails 4: `MyModel.validators` ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3)). This will give you an array containing all validators with options, e.g.:

```
[
    [0] #<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fe542431b40 @attributes=[:name], @options={}>,
    [1] #<UrlValidator:0x007fe542431050 @attributes=[:url], @options={:allow_blank=>true}>
]
```

If you want to get [validation errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors), the option is to pass `@object.errors.messages` through json response.

Additionally you may use [AMS](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.9.0) to serialize model data into json ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ty, it is easy to pass errors back, I know. It looks cool with `validators`, but I will need to write serializer for those class instances and AMS will not give much help. I wonder, is there any ready to use solution?

Comment: I couldn't find any rtu solutions out there. However it shouldn't take too long to get the hash you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976553/rails-serializing-a-models-validators-into-json

Comment: Sadness. I thought Rails is so big project, that it will definitly have this problem solved at least months before it was solved in Django. It seems Django is better at building REST services, damn...